# Ordenar alfabeticamente dos columnas, PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

tengo el siguiente query:

```
 SELECT carreras.nombre,grupos_acta.grado,count(grupos_acta.grado) AS grupos ,sum(hombres),sum(mujeres),descripcion 
 FROM control.asignacion_grupos
 INNER JOIN control.grupos_acta ON grupos_acta.id = id_grupos_acta
 INNER JOIN control.carreras ON carreras.id = id_carreras
 INNER JOIN control.estadistica ON estadistica.id_asignacion_grupos = asignacion_grupos.id
 INNER JOIN control.modalidad ON modalidad.id = id_modalidad
 WHERE id_ciclos = 4 AND grupos_acta.id_campus = 1 AND carreras.tipo=1
 GROUP BY descripcion,carreras.nombre,grupos_acta.grado
 ORDER BY nombre ASC
```

el cual me da como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El query me da los datos que yo pido, el detalle que tengo es que necesito ordenar alfabeticamente dos columnas la que son **nombre** y **descripcion**,
e intentado hacer `ORDER BY nombre,descripcion ASC`, pero no logro obtener resultados, me gustaria saber cual seria la forma correcta de ordenar dos columnas alfabeticamente, es decir, que **Licenciatura en administracion de empresas** y su **descripcion** empieze en escolarizado, espero hacerme entender, gracias.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**
De igual forma e intenado el otro tipo, pero no me da los resultados que quiero.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Según la documentación de [PostGres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) _Note that ordering options apply only to the expression they follow; for example ORDER BY x, y DESC does not mean the same thing as ORDER BY x DESC, y DESC._ Según eso, se tendría que ordenar primero descripcion que nombre. La verdad que estaré al tanto de porque te ocurre esto.

Comment: Si lo que dices es correcto, he intentado eso pero no me respera el ordenamiento `ORDER BY descripcion ASC,nombre ASC`

Comment: Sinceramente ahora que me fijo mejor me acabo de dar cuenta de que en tu consulta simplemente ordenas por nombre. Evidentemente por eso te sale así. Yo me estaba fijando solamente en la parte `ORDER BY nombre,descripcion ASC` y por eso no entendía la imagen. ¿Qué resultados te da con `ORDER BY descripcion ASC,nombre ASC`?

Comment: Por favor pon el resultado que obtienes al hacer `ORDER BY descripcion ASC,nombre ASC`, porque tu resultado actual no hace sentido. También postea los tipos de datos de cada columna

Comment: de igual forma ya hice los que me indicas, dejo edito la pregunta para evitar confuciones.

Comment: lo que posteaste es `ORDER BY descripcion, nombre`, no quieres el orden primero por `nombre`?, por favor aclara bien tu pregunta

Comment: @MiguelOsorio hermano yo veo que arroja el resultado que quieres puesto que esta ordenando primero descripcion y luego ordena los nombres, entonces no esta clara tu pregunta o el resultado que quieres. Por favor edita tu pregunta y coloca un ejemplo con una tabla hecha a mano en cualquier herramienta de texto simulando el resultado.

Answer (score 2):

Solucion:

```
SELECT carreras.nombre,grupos_acta.grado,count(grupos_acta.grado) AS grupos ,sum(hombres),sum(mujeres),descripcion 
 FROM control.asignacion_grupos
 INNER JOIN control.grupos_acta ON grupos_acta.id = id_grupos_acta
 INNER JOIN control.carreras ON carreras.id = id_carreras
 INNER JOIN control.estadistica ON estadistica.id_asignacion_grupos = asignacion_grupos.id
 INNER JOIN control.modalidad ON modalidad.id = id_modalidad
 WHERE id_ciclos = 4 AND grupos_acta.id_campus = 1 AND carreras.tipo=1
 GROUP BY descripcion,carreras.nombre,grupos_acta.grado
 ORDER BY carreras.nombre,descripcion ASC
```

veo que en tu consulta no tienes ambas columnas en el `ORDER BY`

**Actualización 1:** 
Tu dices:

> Licenciatura en administración de empresas y su descripción empiece en escolarizado

Veo que tienes

```
Domingos
Escolarizados
Sabados
```

Su orden alfabético es tal cual PostgreSql te lo esta ordenando de manera en que tu lo indiques `ASC` o `DESC` y lo hace correctamente. Creo que tienes una confusión en el orden alfabético, porque es:

> A,B,C,D (Domingos),E (Escolarizado),F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S (Sábados),T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z

Answer (score 1):

El problema no es el `ORDER BY`, debe funcionar poniendo simplemente: **`ORDER BY nombre,descripcion ASC`**, el siguiente fiddle (simplificado) así lo demuestra.

Si no te funciona poniendo eso debe haber un problema en los `JOIN` o en el `GROUP BY` o en otra parte.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e8c55/1)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

```
create table carrera (
    id serial primary key,
    nombre character varying (50),
    descripcion character varying (20)
);

insert into carrera (nombre,descripcion) values 
('Licenciatura Adm. de Empresas','Domingos'),
('Licenciatura Adm. de Empresas','Sábados'),
('Licenciatura Adm. de Empresas','Domingos'),
('Licenciatura Adm. de Empresas','Escolarizado'),
('Licenciatura Adm. de Empresas','Domingos'),
('Licenciatura Adm. de Empresas','Domingos'),
('Licenciatura Adm. de Empresas','Sábados'),
('Licenciatura Adm. de Empresas','Domingos'),
('Licenciatura Adm. de Empresas','Escolarizado'),
('Licenciatura Adm. de Empresas','zzz'),
('aaaa','bbb'),
('aaaa','ccc'),
('aaaa','ddd'),
('zzzz','aaaa'),
('zzzz','bb'),
('zzzz','c'),
('zzzz','d'),
('zzzz','e')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM 
  carrera
ORDER BY nombre,descripcion ASC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e8c55/1/0)**:

```
| id |                        nombre |  descripcion |
|----|-------------------------------|--------------|
| 11 |                          aaaa |          bbb |
| 12 |                          aaaa |          ccc |
| 13 |                          aaaa |          ddd |
|  5 | Licenciatura Adm. de Empresas |     Domingos |
|  1 | Licenciatura Adm. de Empresas |     Domingos |
|  6 | Licenciatura Adm. de Empresas |     Domingos |
|  3 | Licenciatura Adm. de Empresas |     Domingos |
|  8 | Licenciatura Adm. de Empresas |     Domingos |
|  4 | Licenciatura Adm. de Empresas | Escolarizado |
|  9 | Licenciatura Adm. de Empresas | Escolarizado |
|  7 | Licenciatura Adm. de Empresas |      Sábados |
|  2 | Licenciatura Adm. de Empresas |      Sábados |
| 10 | Licenciatura Adm. de Empresas |          zzz |
| 14 |                          zzzz |         aaaa |
| 15 |                          zzzz |           bb |
| 16 |                          zzzz |            c |
| 17 |                          zzzz |            d |
| 18 |                          zzzz |            e |
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que en la tabla `modalidad` es donde está el campo `descripcion`, veo que la consulta está ordenada primero por nombre y luego por descripción y el resultado corresponde a ello. Sin embargo, podrías tener mejor control del orden agregando un campo entero `posicion` en la tabla de `modalidad`, de esta forma podrías tener

```
 ORDER BY nombre, modalidad.posicion
```

Comment: ¿Acaso no se pide ordenar por nombre y descripción? No entiendo cómo está solución aplicaría para lo que se está preguntando

Comment: Pues si, quiere ordenarlo por nombre y descripción, sin embargo, al parecer lo que quiere es una ordenamiento 'personalizado'. Es la forma en que puede solucionar que primero le aparezca 'ESCOLARIZADO' y luego 'DOMINGO'.